# if value is in another table then select certain columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a statement that works how i would like, however is it the correct way as i have lots of IF statements and wondering if it have an impact on performance or i should be taking a different approach for best practise. This was created from reading documentation so i might have gone the log way around it.

```
SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, 
IF( c.id IN  (SELECT client_id  FROM bookings)  AND '1' IN (SELECT practitioner_id FROM bookings) , c.address1, NULL) as address1,
IF( c.id IN  (SELECT client_id  FROM bookings)  AND '1' IN (SELECT practitioner_id FROM bookings) , c.address2, NULL) as address2,  
IF( c.id IN  (SELECT client_id  FROM bookings)  AND '1' IN (SELECT practitioner_id FROM bookings) , c.town, NULL) as town, 
IF( c.id IN  (SELECT client_id  FROM bookings)  AND '1' IN (SELECT practitioner_id FROM bookings) , c.county, NULL) as county,  
IF( c.id IN  (SELECT client_id  FROM bookings)  AND '1' IN (SELECT practitioner_id FROM bookings) , c.postcode, NULL) as postcode,  
IF( c.id IN  (SELECT client_id  FROM bookings)  AND '1' IN (SELECT practitioner_id FROM bookings) , c.email, NULL) as email,  
IF( c.id IN  (SELECT client_id  FROM bookings)  AND '1' IN (SELECT practitioner_id FROM bookings) , c.dob, NULL) as dob 
FROM clients c
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: No, this is definitely not correct and it most probably is giving you wrong results unless you have only one row in bookings table. Take this here `AND '1' IN (SELECT practitioner_id FROM bookings)` it is completely disregarding the previous statement which it appears to check if that c.id is in the table bookings. You may have thought that it should relate to it but it is not.

Comment: i am trying to only return client information if they have been booked in with the current person logged in, otherwise the person logged in can only see first and last name. the statement gives to correct output, just want to make sure im not learning bad habits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a different approach.

I am guessing that you want the additional columns when the corresponding booking has a practitioner of 1.  I'm not 100% sure, because your query does something slightly different.

But the general idea is something like this:

```
SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name,
       (CASE WHEN b.client_id IS NOT NULL THEN c.address1 END) as address1,
       . . .
FROM clients c LEFT JOIN
     bookings b
     ON c.id = b.client_id AND b.practitioner_id = 1;
```

Fill in the `. . .` with the additional columns you want.

Comment: that works as well, can i have some more information why using case is better? Thanks

Comment: @bish25 . . . `CASE` is ANSI standard syntax.  I prefer standard syntax.  But that is the least important change in this query.